# Heroku custom domain shows theres nothing there yet

Tags: heroku

Added custom domain on heroku, the page says "There's nothing here, yet."

Steps done:

1. Domain is connected and can be accessed (used 'heroku add domain domain.com' to make sure)
2. Added CNAME record of given dns server.
3. Waited for 24 hours
4. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796355/heroku-custom-domain-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683844/deployed-heroku-app-not-showing-up-on-custom-domain)

   [image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Next time add www to your domain in Heroku (not domain parking provider).